# Unicode character ⁡ (U+2061) (inputenc) not set up for use with LaTeX

Tags: symbols

I am writing this equation:

```
{min}_G{max}_DL_{GAN}(D,G)=E_x\sim P_R [log D(x)]+E_z\simP_z[log⁡(1-D(G(z)))]
```

It gives me the error:

```
! Package inputenc Error: Unicode character ⁡ (U+2061)
  (inputenc)              not set up for use with LaTeX.
```

Comment: You have an invisible symbol after the last `log`. It isn'r supported by LaTeX.

Comment: There is an invisible character U+2061 (FUNCTION APPLICATION) between the second `log` and the following opening parenthesis. You can paste your text to https://w3c.github.io/xml-entities/unicode-names.html and investigate all characters.

Comment: Usually you'd write `\log` instead of `log` for the logarithm in LaTeX. There are also operators for minimum (`\min`) and maximum (`\max`).

Comment: i have removed the invisible symbol after the log but the error persists and also try using \log and \max the error stays.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 4):

What I frequently do when I encounter pesky invisible characters in an equation is to (a) switch from pdfLaTeX to LuaLaTeX and (b) make sure to load the `unicode-math` package. That way, invisible characters such as `U+2061 (FUNCTION APPLICATION)` show up in the pdf file -- see the first line in the screenshot below. This makes it straightforward to locate and delete these characters. Once you've performed this step, you can go back to pdfLaTeX if you wish.

To make your equation ready for LaTeX, you should also (a) replace `{min}` and `{max}` with `\min` and `\max` and (b) replace of instances of `log` with `\log`. And, changing `\simP` to `\sim P` will help avoid getting an error message.

[image]

```
% !TEX TS-program = lualatex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}      % for 'gather*' environment
\usepackage{unicode-math} % to make the invis. char. visible
\begin{document}
\begin{gather*}
{min}_G{max}_DL_{GAN}(D,G)=E_x\sim P_R [log D(x)]+E_z\sim P_z[log⁡(1-D(G(z)))] \\
\min_{G}\max_{D}L_{GAN}(D,G)=E_x\sim P_R [\log D(x)]+E_z\sim P_z[\log(1-D(G(z)))]
\end{gather*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Great answer! If the OP doesn’t want the limit D to go under min and max like that, `\min\nolimits_C` and `\max\nolimits_D`.